# Update Panel Not Working on Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

For some reason my update panel will not work on the server it works local on our test server and local dev boxes.

I have the following code for my update panel within a jquery model

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:left;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span  style="display:none;" class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" align="center">10% Off Your Frist Order!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="input-group">
      <img src="" width="100%" alt="10% Off First Order" />
            <div style="float:left">
               *excludes.</div> 
           <div ></div>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter Email for Discount"  CssClass="emailField"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
         <asp:label runat="server" id="lblVoucher"  style="font-size:16px;"></asp:label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblblerror" runat="server"  ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                <asp:button runat="server" CausesValidation = "false" class="btn btn-primary  "   

               ID ="btnNewGetVoucher"    style="background-color:#007B78;color:white;align-self:center;height:55px;width:100%"  text="Get Voucher Code" />
  </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- Make sure to include the 'nothanks' class on the buttons -->

   </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Then my button handle event is as follows

```
 Protected Sub btnNewGetVoucher_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewGetVoucher.Click


 End Sub
```

Screen shot showing debugging.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qff3.jpg

The reason why I have my button inside the update panel is that I want it to disappear when the customer clicks get voucher but please if anybody think that is wrong way to do it please let me no.

**Note:**
I checked both web configs to make sure that the mode was not set to legacy and indeed it was commented out

```
<!--<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />-->
```

Oh and the demo site and live site are on sep instances on the same iis so I no its not a case of its not installed.

Just for extended clarity here is my code that calls the modal.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

        // Delayed Modal Display + Cookie On Click
        $(document).ready(function () {

            console.log("Popup Code");


            $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                // we want to trap the user closing the popup and we also set the cookie expiery here to seven days.
                $.cookie('mycookie', 'true', { expires: 604800000, path: '/' });
            })
            //if the cooke when the modal has been created is empty then display
            //the second one is for 
            if ($.cookie("mycookie") == null) {
                console.log("Popup Start");
                // Show the modal, with delay func.
                $('#myModal').appendTo("body");                
                $("#myModal").appendTo("form:first");           
                function show_modal() {
                    $.cookie('mycookie', 'true', { expires: 604800000, path: '/' });
                 $('#myModal').modal();
                    console.log("Popup Displayed after mymodal");
                }             
                // Set delay func. time in milliseconds
                window.setTimeout(show_modal, 10000);
            }




        });
</script>
```

Comment: @Skyblade any ideas or you just an editor

Comment: Just an editor. Your code has nothing with the toolkit, don't put extra tags here, it's confusing.